# .net MAUI DataTemplate with a CollectionView that contains <ContentPresenter /> in its ItemTemplate, "No installed components were detected"

Tags: c#, uicollectionview, maui, controltemplate, contentpresenter

We have a number of Views that display a list of Models and in each of those views, tapping on an Item displays an action sheet.

Everything is working well but we want to utilize the ControlTemplate to ensure consistency across views.  First attempt seemed to work but it turns out it only worked because the ItemsSource had just one item in it.  Once an ItemsSource contained more than one item, then a "No installed components were detected" exception was thrown.  The first item was still rendered appropriately and tapping on it functioned as expected.

Here are the files in play:

ListViewsTemplate.xaml (control template)

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MauiIssues.Controls.ListViewsTemplate"
         ControlTemplate="{DynamicResource ContainerTemplate}"
         x:Name="this">
<ContentView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ContainerTemplate">
            <Frame BindingContext="{x:Reference this}" Padding="10, 0, 10, 0">
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout><LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" /></CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Frame>
                                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                            Command="{TemplateBinding ItemTapped}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Frame>
                                <Rectangle IsVisible="{OnPlatform false, Android=True}" HeightRequest="2" Fill="Black"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </Frame>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>
```

ListViewsTemplate.xaml.cs (control template)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MauiIssues.Controls
{
    public partial class ListViewsTemplate : ContentView
    {
        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(ListViewsTemplate), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);
        
        public ICommand ItemTapped
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(ItemTappedProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemTappedProperty, value);
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTappedProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemTapped), typeof(ICommand), typeof(ListViewsTemplate), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public ListViewsTemplate() { InitializeComponent(); }

    }
}
```

ListViewsTemplate.xaml (content page)

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MauiIssues.Models"
             xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:MauiIssues.Controls"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MauiIssues.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MauiIssues.Views.ListViewsTemplate"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:ListViewsTemplateViewModel">
    <uc:ListViewsTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTapped="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
        <Label BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type model:ListViewsTemplateModel}}}" 
               x:DataType="{x:Type model:ListViewsTemplateModel}" 
               Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </uc:ListViewsTemplate>
</ContentPage>
```

ListViewsTemplate.xaml.cs (content page)

```
using MauiIssues.ViewModels;

namespace MauiIssues.Views
{
    public partial class ListViewsTemplate : ContentPage
    {
        public ListViewsTemplateViewModel ViewModel { get; }

        public ListViewsTemplate()
        {
            base.BindingContext = this.ViewModel = new ListViewsTemplateViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            await this.ViewModel.OnAppearing();
            base.OnAppearing();
        }
    }
}
```

ListViewsTemplateViewModel.cs (view model)

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using MauiIssues.Models;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MauiIssues.ViewModels
{
    public partial class ListViewsTemplateViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ListViewsTemplateModel> Items { get; } = new ();

        [RelayCommand]
        async Task ItemTapped(ListViewsTemplateModel item)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("tapped item", item.Name, "OK");
        }

        public async Task OnAppearing() 
        {
            this.Items.Add(new ListViewsTemplateModel() { Name = $"Item {this.Items.Count + 1}" });
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

When you first navigate to the view, everything is good to go.  When you navigate away and come back to the view you get:

No installed components were detected.

at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
at WinRT.DelegateExtensions.DynamicInvokeAbi(Delegate del, Object[] invoke_params)
at ABI.System.Collections.Generic.IVectorMethods`1.Append(IObjectReference obj, T value) at ABI.System.Collections.Generic.IListMethods`1.Add(IObjectReference obj, T item)
at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.UIElementCollection.Add(UIElement item)
at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.UpdateContent(IContentViewHandler handler)
at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.MapContent(IContentViewHandler handler, IContentView page)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueActual(BindableProperty property, BindablePropertyContext context, Object value, Boolean currentlyApplying, SetValueFlags attributes, Boolean silent)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueCore(BindableProperty property, Object value, SetValueFlags attributes, SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindingExpression.ApplyCore(Object sourceObject, BindableObject target, BindableProperty property, Boolean fromTarget)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindingExpression.Apply(Object sourceObject, BindableObject target, BindableProperty property)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Binding.d__27.MoveNext()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.b__128_0(Object state)
at Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueueSynchronizationContext.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.g__Throw|20_0(Int32 hr)
at ABI.Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.IUnhandledErrorMethods.Propagate(IObjectReference _obj)
at Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.UnhandledError.Propagate()
at Microsoft.AppCenter.Utils.ApplicationLifecycleHelperWinUI.<.ctor>b__0_3(Object sender, UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs eventArgs)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AppCenter.Utils.ApplicationLifecycleHelperWinUI.<.ctor>b__0_3(Object sender, UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs eventArgs)
at WinRT.EventSource__EventHandler`1.EventState.<GetEventInvoke>b__1_0(Object obj, T e) at ABI.System.EventHandler`1.Do_Abi_Invoke[TAbi](Void* thisPtr, IntPtr sender, TAbi args)

**UPDATE:**

To provide a little more clarity, what this is trying to accomplish is the same as what a Master Page does in asp.net.

Page.Master

```
<body>
   <div class="main">
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FilterContent" runat="server" />
       <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />
       <div class="filterseparator" />
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="GridContent" runat="server" />
       <div class="gridseparator" />
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
   </div>
</body>
```

Here each web page uses the Master Page and then places their own controls within the ContentPlaceHolders which is (to our understanding) what the ContentPresenter is for.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put the label into `uc:ListViewsTemplate`:

```xml
<uc:ListViewsTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTapped="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
            <!--<Label BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type model:ListViewsTemplateModel}}}"
               x:DataType="{x:Type model:ListViewsTemplateModel}"
               Text="{Binding Name}" />-->
</uc:ListViewsTemplate>
```

Because then the ContentView(ListViewsTemplate) you created will lose its meaning. So, put it into `ListViewsTemplate`:

```xml
.....
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Frame>
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{TemplateBinding ItemTapped}" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

            <!-- Put it here or anywhere else you like -->
            <Label x:DataType="{x:Type model:ListViewsTemplateModel}" 
                   Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </Frame>
        <Rectangle IsVisible="{OnPlatform false, Android=True}" HeightRequest="2" Fill="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
.....
```

I tested it, and it works well.

**Update**

```xml
<DataTemplate>
  <Grid>
    <Frame>
      <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{TemplateBinding ItemTapped}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
      </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
      
      <!-- use stacklayout -->
      <StackLayout>
        <ContentPresenter/>
        <Label x:DataType="{x:Type model:ListViewsTemplateModel}" 
               Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </StackLayout>
      
    </Frame>
    <Rectangle IsVisible="{OnPlatform false, Android=True}" HeightRequest="2" Fill="Black"/>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: But then I can no longer have other Views use something other than a label.

For example another view may have a label and an image.

Comment: Use `StackLayout` to add as many views as you want. I updated the answer, and wish it can help you ;)

Comment: We still get the same error after wrapping the `<ContentPresenter/>` with a `<StackLayout>`.  Again, works when `<CollectionView ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}">` has just one item, throws that same error when there is more than one.

Just for confirmation you are still working with a CollectionView inside your ControlTemplate right?

Comment: I post a new answer, wish it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Remove the label in `uc:ListViewsTemplate`:

```xml
<uc:ListViewsTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTapped="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
            <!--<Label BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type model:ListViewsTemplateModel}}}"
               x:DataType="{x:Type model:ListViewsTemplateModel}"
               Text="{Binding Name}" />-->
</uc:ListViewsTemplate>
```

In your ListViewsTemplate.xaml:

```xml
.....
<DataTemplate>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Frame Grid.Row="0">
      <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{TemplateBinding ItemTapped}" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
      </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
      <StackLayout>
        <Label x:DataType="{x:Type model:ListViewsTemplateModel}" 
               Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" IsVisible="{OnPlatform false, Android=True}" HeightRequest="2" Fill="Black"/>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
.....
```

Here is the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/HhSD3nS).

**Solution 2**
Create a ContentPage and put these codes into it:

```xml
.....
<ContentPage.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ContainerTemplate">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Frame Grid.Row="0">
          <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{TemplateBinding Path=Parent.BindingContext.ItemTappedCommand}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type model:ListViewsTemplateModel}}}"/>
          </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
          <ContentPresenter/>
        </Frame>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" IsVisible="{OnPlatform false, Android=True}" HeightRequest="2" Fill="Black"/>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Frame Padding="10, 0, 10, 0">
  <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
      <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ContainerTemplate}">
          <Label x:DataType="{x:Type model:ListViewsTemplateModel}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </ContentView>
      </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
  </CollectionView>
</Frame>
.....
```

.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage
{
    public ListViewsTemplateViewModel ViewModel { get; }

    public NewPage1()
    {
        base.BindingContext = this.ViewModel = new ListViewsTemplateViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        await this.ViewModel.OnAppearing();
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

You can also put codes of ContentPage.Resources into App.xaml:

```xml
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml"/>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <!-- you can also put codes of ContentPage.Resources into here --> 
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ContainerTemplate">
            ......
    </ControlTemplate>
    
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And here is the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/zfHSNRM).

Comment: First let me say Thank You for the time that you have put into this.  Instead of working with what we attempted and applying your suggestions it is probably best to start fresh with your solution and highlight what it doesn't cover.

We are able to get your solution to work on Android, spent too much time figuring out why it wasn't working and it turns out the label does not render on screen in Windows.  If you can reproduce the windows issue please create an internal ticket.

Will list issues with your approach in a following comment.

Comment: - We have 4 views that are single labeled bound to different models that extend BaseNamedModel.  Your approach will work for those 4.
- We have 3 views that have two labels bound to different properties of a model
- We have 1 view that has a label and a button, label bound to property, button bound to command of its ViewModel
- We have 2 views that have one label and it uses Multi-Binding to multiple properties
- We have 2 view that have one label and one image bound to different properties
- We have 1 view that has one label but it is bound to something other than 'Name'

Comment: With your approach we would have to define 6 different Frames with a CollectionView in it.  We are attempting to avoid creating the 6 Frames that are exactly the same except which controls the CollectionView uses to render the bound item on screen.

Comment: Accepting that 4 views covered by one set of code is better than none, we saw a possible issue with your approach.  1 of our 4 views you have the ability to add to the ItemsSource without leaving the view.  We noticed that while the ObservableCollection does indeed get updated, the screen does not render the new item.  Can you confirm this?  Just add a button to your ContentPage and bind it to a new command in the ViewModel that adds an item to the ObservableCollection.